# How to return a promise in such case?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase with JavaScript and I know that I can return a promise with the output of retrieved data. But I can't really see it through in the following case:

```
filterUsersAndCalculateMatches = (userProfile, userID, potentialMatches, maxDistanceToSearchForMatches) => {
   const TOTAL_SCORE = 100;
   var matches = {}; // Matches to be stored in the database
   potentialMatches.forEach(user => {
     if (user.val() !== userID) {

           databaseRef.child(`users/${user.val()}/profile`).once("value", (snapshot) => {
             const matchScore = calculateMatchScore(userProfile, snapshot.val(), maxDistanceToSearchForMatches);
             //console.log("final score is " + matchScore);
             if (matchScore) {
               const match = {
                   compatibility: matchScore / TOTAL_SCORE,
                   distance: distance,
                   profile: snapshot.val()
               }
               matches[user.val()] = match;
             }
           });
     }
   });
 };
```

I am iterating over users' IDs and accessing their profiles to do some calculations and add the result along with their profiles to an object.

How to return a promise the matches object after all users have been gone through ?

Comment: Could you give more context to what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) returns a promise.
You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Promise.all() gets an array of promises as an argument, and it returns a promise, that it will resolve when all passed promises resolve.
The modified code would look like:

```js
filterUsersAndCalculateMatches = (userProfile, userID, potentialMatches, maxDistanceToSearchForMatches) => {
  var matches = {}; // Matches to be stored in the database
  const promisesList = [];
  potentialMatches.forEach(user => {
    if (user.val() !== userID) {
        // save a reference to the promise
        const dataPromise = databaseRef.child(`users/${user.val()}/profile`).once("value", (snapshot) => {
            // ...
          });
        // push the promise in the promise list
        promiseList.push(dataPromise);
    }
  });

  return Promise.all(promisesList).then(() => Promise.resolve(matches));
};
```

You might want to resolve even if one of the promises in the list is rejected.
You can do the following, handle rejected promises.

```js
promiseList.push(
  // have to handle the reject
  dataPromise
    .then(data => data)
    // returns a resolved promise with { error } object.
    // doing this Promise.all() will always resolve even if some of them are rejected.
    .catch(error => {
      return { error: error };
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and when I log the returned promise I get a pending one ... How can I extract the matches ?

Comment: You can add a handle for promises that do not resolve. Promise.all() will only resolve if all promises are resolved. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a promise which resolves with the `matches` object when the iteration over the profiles is done. Note I didn't handle errors

```js
filterUsersAndCalculateMatches = (userProfile, userID, potentialMatches, maxDistanceToSearchForMatches) => {
  //Return a new promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const TOTAL_SCORE = 100;
    var matches = {}; // Matches to be stored in the database
    var promises = []; // create an array for promises during iteration over profiles
    potentialMatches.forEach(user => {
      if (user.val() !== userID) {
        // Save promise in var p
        var p = databaseRef.child(`users/${user.val()}/profile`).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
          const matchScore = calculateMatchScore(userProfile, snapshot.val(), maxDistanceToSearchForMatches);
          //console.log("final score is " + matchScore);
          if (matchScore) {
            const match = {
              compatibility: matchScore / TOTAL_SCORE,
              distance: distance,
              profile: snapshot.val()
            }
            matches[user.val()] = match;
          }
        });
        promises.push(p);
      }
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(resolve.bind(resolve, matches));
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and when I log the returned promise I get a pending one ... How can I extract the matches ?

Comment: If you log the returned `promise` right away, it will be `pending` because the async function isn't done execution. To get the matches, you have to grab it via a `then` function. Then `then` function is executed when the async operation completes. For example:

`
filterUsersAndCalculateMatches(arg1, arg2 ...)
 .then((matches) => {
   console.log(matches)
 })
`

Comment: That does it ... Thank you very much for your help. I have to give the correct answer to bogdanpetru though as he was the first to answer however I rated your comment. Thanks again.

Comment: sure! It's all good. When I started answering, I had to look up Firebase API to make sure I'm giving you the right answer. I have no experience with Firebase. If I saw bogdanpetru's answer, I won't have posted mine since they are semantically the same. Glad you got your solution.